# Dense Error using Keras

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, keras

I am getting an error that seems to be a common problem for beginners in Keras. I am trying to classify a color image as 'something' or 'not_something' and get basic model running so I can tweak the hyper-parameters to get a better understanding of what they all do.

I would like it if someone could explain why I am getting my error specifically in the model.fit and then explain what I should be concerned with/looking for in the general sense of dimensionality before hand (in train and test sets). I am not sure if the Dense(units) should be 1 in the case of a binary classifier of 2, could you explain this as well?

Error:

```

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_18 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (584, 1)
```

```

Code:

```

```
from identify_mounds import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(6)
import os
import subprocess
from collections import defaultdict
import pickle
from scipy.misc import imread
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils


def train_nomound_mound(dic):
    X = []
    y = []
    X_ = []

    for im in dic:
        X.extend(dic[im]['img_lst'])
        y.extend(dic[im]['label'])

    for im in X:
        arr = imread(im)
        X_.append(arr)

    X_ = (np.array(X_).reshape(779, 4, 16, 16)/255).astype('float32')
    y = np.array(y).astype('float32')

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_, y, stratify = y)

    #Demensions: X_train: (584, 4, 16, 16), y_train: (584,), X_test:  (195, 4, 16, 16), y_test: (195,) 

    model = Sequential()

    batch_size = 128
    nb_epoch = 12

    nb_filters = 32
    kernel_size = (3, 3)
    input_shape = (4, 16, 16)
    pool_size = (2, 2)

    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], activation='relu'))
    # model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))


    model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.50))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adadelta', metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test score:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

```

Comment: To start, you are missing a [Flatten](https://keras.io/layers/core/#flatten) layer between your Conv2D and Dense layers.  Using `model.summary()` is a helpful way to track the shape of the tensors as they propagate through your network.

Comment: Change the shape of your last dense layer. It should have the number of units equal to number of classes, so that it can return the softmax output

Comment: Thanks! also realized I had two convolutional layers for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dense layer with a single neuron is suitable when using the `binary_crossentropy` loss.  The `categorical_crossentropy` loss requires one-hot encoding and the same number of neurons as categories in the final output layer.  From the [Keras loss documentation](https://keras.io/losses/#categorical_crossentropy):

> Note: when using the categorical_crossentropy loss, your targets
>   should be in categorical format (e.g. if you have 10 classes, the
>   target for each sample should be a 10-dimensional vector that is
>   all-zeros expect for a 1 at the index corresponding to the class of
>   the sample).

One-hot encoding via the `to_categorical` function is illustrated concisely in the Keras [MNIST MLP example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py).